For high power laser diode, how to determine relation between limit values of pulse duration, repetition rate, and energy?
For a work project I have a laser diode of 808 nm wavelength. It allows current of 190 A at which it gives 2400 W of optical power. According to data sheet, at this current the allowed repetition rate is 3 Hz for 10 ms pulse duration. From experiments I know that for 190 A current laser diode can easily handle, without short term damages, a repetition rate of 5 Hz at 5 ms pulses. Also, from the data sheet I know, that at 155 A (1800 W) and 30 ms pulse a diode can handle 2 Hz; at 60 A (600 W) and 300 ms pulse diode can handle 1 Hz.
Now, I know for a fact that, for example at 1200 W of optical power and 20 ms pulse I can have from a diode 15 Hz repetition rate without a problem. Finally my question is: how can I determine relation between limit values power (or current) pulse width and repetition rate? How one affects another while the third one remains the same? For example, If at 2400 W and 10 ms i have 3 Hz, what pulse width I can use if I decrease power to 2000 W and will remain at 3 Hz?
So far I tried different extrapolations, but without a big success. But I feel like I am missing something that is fundamental.
If it helps, I know the relation between the wavelength and junction temperature (thermal shift).

The temperature of the laser is the "key". Do you know some thermal "constants"?

Well, I don't think I have some specific constants. I can deduce the diode p-n junction temperature from the radiated wavelength (it is a linear dependence). So, theoretically I though that I can state that I shall not go over 100 degC in peak and 70 degC in average (in 1 s), but these values are purely my estimation. And just measure spectrum of parameters, but I don't feel like this is a correct way. The supplier does not provide any limit values for temperature, besides recommended coolant temp (20-25 degC). But if you have some experience in this area, I would gladly make some assumptions.

What is the specification datasheet of this diode?

Here is the link to the G drive with the datasheet:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MEQFm5fcCTRB6wnF-ECSJnX6eqNKrAAx?usp=drive_link

I would email Coherent and ask them how to properly estimate the safe operating area of the laser.
